# imagick php 8, Конвертация svg to png - портит картинку

Tags: php, laravel, svg, png, imagick

Всем привет! Есть задача по конвертации svg -> png.
Реализовал на локальном окружении - все хорошо
На сервере вот так:

[image: Результат конвертации]

Код:

```
$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($content);
$img->setImageFormat("png24");
Storage::disk('local')->put('/public' . $path . '/' . $fileName . '.png', $img->getimageblob(), 'public');
```

Comment: Стоит указать различие пакетов на машине, где все хорошо, и на машине, где все плохо. в частности версии PHP, web-сервера, если используете, библиотеки мэджика, самого меджика

Comment: А в чём порча? Фон не добавил? Цвет текста не тот?